# Axios not sending httpOnly cooke back to server

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have my reactjs app that I need to send httpOnly cookie back to server for refreshToken my code is below but I can't get it in server.

```
const response = await axios.get('/refresh', {
  withCredentials: true
});
```

Comment: Are you getting a message about CORS?

Comment: Are you working with not a localhost API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my Asp.net Core server and solved it by added below to my startup class.

```
    app.UseCors(x => x
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .SetIsOriginAllowed(host => true) // allow any origin
         .AllowCredentials()); // allow credentials
```